# How to define (programmatically) a transition in AnimatedStateListDrawable

Tags: android, statelistdrawable, animator

The new drawable selector `AnimatedStateListDrawable` allows to define animations when the selector goes from one state to another.
In the documentation, and so far in the web, there are only examples of XML definitions of this new class.
My problem is: I want to create it **programmatically**:

```
    AnimatedStateListDrawable astld= new AnimatedStateListDrawable();
    astld.addState(KEY_STATE_PRESSED, pressedKey);
    astld.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, normalKey);
    astld.addTransition(??????????????);
```

but I cannot find where can I get, or set, the states IDs (**fromId** and **toId**) needed for the transition.

> **public void addTransition (int *fromId*, int *toId*, T *transition*, boolean *reversible*)**
>   Added in API level 21
>   Adds a new transition between keyframes.
>
> Parameters:
>   **fromId** Unique identifier of the starting keyframe
>   **toId** Unique identifier of the ending keyframe
>   **transition** An Animatable drawable to use as a transition, may not be null
>   **reversible** Whether the transition can be reversed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found finally that there is a new method `addState()` with a different signature, which includes the parameter for the ID.

> **public void addState (int[] stateSet, Drawable drawable, int id)**
> Added in API level 21
> Add a new drawable to the set of keyframes.
>
> Parameters
> **stateSet** An array of resource IDs to associate with the keyframe
> **drawable** The drawable to show when in the specified state, may not be null
> **id** The unique identifier for the keyframe

Comment: Could you explain what is meant by your answer? are these private constants? An example would be awesome